# Switching platform toolet from v140 to v110 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: php, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I'm porting a source code for a PHP extension that was originally written for UNIX environment.

I have resolved all library dependencies and compiled it successfuly, however the EasyPHP server that we use for testing refuses to load the DLL module.

I have assumed it's because I've compiled the DLL using Visual Studio 2015 (v140) platform toolset while original PHP the server uses v11 source, as far as I know.

However, changing the project from v140 to Visual Studio 2012 (v110) toolset produces the following errors:

```
LNK1120 5 unresolved externals  DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    

LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf   DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(dump.obj)

LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf   DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(error.obj)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____acrt_iob_func referenced in function _json_loadf    DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(load.obj)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function __vsnprintf_l  DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(load.obj)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__strtoll referenced in function _lex_scan_number   DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(load.obj)

LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp____stdio_common_vsprintf   DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(strconv.obj)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp___dclass referenced in function _json_real DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(value.obj)

LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __ltod3 referenced in function _json_number_value    DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\[...]\jansson_d.lib(value.obj)

LNK2005 _sprintf already defined in jansson_d.lib(dump.obj) DINAPIS_PHP_MATH    D:\Projects\Dinapis PHP Math\php-extension-win\DINAPIS_PHP_MATH\DINAPIS_PHP_MATH\MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
```

As you can see, this "jansson" library produces all the problems and has given me headaches with original porting as well.

So what is v110 toolset missing that produces these errors, when v140 compiles fine? How to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: That last line is saying the static jansson library has MS C runtime functions defined in it.  There should be a way to compile that library so it doesn't pull in the C runtime functions.  But I'm not sure how.  Or you could try to use a DLL of that library if it exists.